# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_author' discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

again, I have been thinking about my preparation problem. I'm just getting started writing bots for discord and sitting for a few hours looking for a bug, in the end I don't find it anyway. That's why I am writing a forum post as a last resort. I count on your help, and thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def covid_hour():
    channel = client.get_channel(809881992367702117),
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Dane dot. COVID-19 w Polsce:",
        color = discord.Color.blue(),
    ),
    url = 'API'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        raw_response = await session.get(url)
        response = await raw_response.text()
        response = json.loads(response)
        embed.set_author(name=str(f'{date}'))
        embed.add_field(name='• **Kraj**:', value=str(f"Polska"), inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Nowe zakażenia**:', value=str(f"{response['dailyInfected']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Nowe zgony**:', value=str(f"{response['dailyDeceased']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Nowe testy**:', value=str(f"{respons['dailyTested']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Nowe uzdrowienia**:', value=str(f"{response['dailyRecovered']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Aktualnie zakażonych**:', value=str(f"{respons['activeCase']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Łącznie potwierdzonych**:', value=str(f"{response['infected']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Łączne zgony**:', value=str(f"{response['deceased']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Wyzdrowiałych**:', value=str(f"{response['recovered']}"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Nowych na kwarantannie**:', value=str(f"{response['dailyQuarantine']}"), inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="dBot created by Diablo#4700")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        #await channel.send('``           ``')
```

Error in console:

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'covid_hour'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\konta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 64, in covid_hour
    embed.set_author(name=str2(f'{date}'))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_author'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the line where you create your discord.Embed instance you have a `,` at the very end. This tells python it's a `tuple`. As a result, removing it will fix this issue.